# Identity Server 4 + ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

How to create my own entities and db tables in ASP.Net Core 2 instead of entities that Identity Server 4 creates by default?
[Database created with Identity Server 4 by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrDpt.png)

Comment: What are you looking to do? Extend these tables or completely recreate them? If your looking to extend the tables, then create partials for the existing entity models used by Identity Server 4, and add migrations.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to do? Extend these tables or completely recreate them?

If your looking to extend the tables, then create partials for the existing entity models used by Identity Server 4, and add migrations.

If you don't want to use migrations, take a look at the SQL scripts in the Identity Server 4 documentation :-

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/Host/Migrations/IdentityServer

Comment: I want to create only my own tables if it is possible

Comment: @routtor I don't think that is possible.  You need to have the correct fields for Identity Server 4 to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own entity model. Tie it up to a context and connect it to your database. Have in mind - you must have a corresponding entity for almost all of the IdentityServer entities.

Then you somehow have to map your entities to the IdentityServer ones.

In other words - you have to override the Client store, ApiResource Store, PersistedGrant store, so that they can use your entities and pass them to IdentityServer.

Then also in the AccounController, you must told him to use your UserService (lets suppose that you have one, that is accessing the user entity in your database) and authenticate the user.